# How to upload pfx certificate in Azure and access and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-security

In my web job for decryption, I am using a .pfx certificate. But for more security purpose I have to upload this certificate to Azure store and access it through c#.

Can anyone provide more information(links) on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you could follow the steps below for uploading your PFX file and access it from your app.

**Upload the PFX certificate**

Log into [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com), choose your app service, then click "SETTINGS > SSL certificates", then click **Upload Certificate** as follows for adding your PFX certificate file:

[image]

**Add app setting**

Click "SETTINGS > Application settings" section of your app service, add an app setting named `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with its value set to the thumbprint of your uploaded PFX certificate file as follows:

[image]

**Access from app**

You could leverage the following code snippet for retrieving the certificate as follows:

```html
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                       X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                       “{your-cert's-thumbprint}”,
                       false);
// Get the first cert with the thumbprint
if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
   X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
   // Use certificate
   Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
}
certStore.Close();
```

Additionally, here is a previous blog talking about using certificates in Azure websites applications, you could refer to [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).